# Rails: Different layouts based on different roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 different roles in my app: Guest, User, and Admin.  Certain pages need to have a different layout based on which role is viewing the page.  I was wondering if there's an easier way to do this than what I'm doing.

For example, I currently have 3 different layouts.  And in my VenuesController I have 3 different actions below.  But it seems to me there should be a simpler way.

```
def index
  @venues = Venue.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("name ASC")
end

def admin_index
  @venues = Venue.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("name ASC")
  render layout: "admin"
end

def user_index
  @venues = Venue.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("name ASC")
  render layout: "user"
end
```

I suppose I could have one `index` action and then inside it test what role my current_user has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using layout files named for the roles is fine.

```
def index
  @venues = Venue.paginate(page: params[:page]).order("name ASC")
  # substitute your favorite current_user check and role name method
  render layout: current_user.present? ? current_user.role.name : 'application'
  # app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
  # app/views/layouts/user.html.erb
  # app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
end
```

Note that depending on the actual differences (or not) between these layouts, it may be more straightforward and maintainable to use helpers and such within a single layout to determine the visible content. You can also use role-name'd partials, or slice and dice any of these techniques to whatever degree makes sense to you..

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_women_category, :get_men_category
```

> layout :resolve_layout

```
  def index
  end

  private

  def resolve_layout
    if current_user && current_user.has_role?(:super_admin)
       'superadmin'
    elsif current_user && current_user.has_role?(:company_admin)
       'application'
    else
      'application'
    end
  end

end
```